# A table with a XML field with null value, consumes some space? How much?

Tags: postgresql, disk-access

There are an "official benchmark" or a simple rule of thumb to decide when space or performance will be affected?

---

My table have many simple and indexed fields,

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(250) NOT NULL, 
  ...
  xcontent xml, -- the NULL use disk space?? cut performance?
  ...
  UNIQUE(name)
);
```

and it is a kind of  "[sparse content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)", many `xcontent` values will be NULL... So, **these XML NULLs consumes some disk space?**

---

### Notes

I can normalize, the table `t` now will be `nt`,

```
CREATE TABLE nt (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(250) NOT NULL, 
  ...
  UNIQUE(name)
);

CREATE TABLE nt2 (
  t_id int REFERENCES nt(id),
  xcontent xml NOT NULL
);

CREATE VIEW nt_full AS 
   SELECT nt.*, nt2.xcontnt FROM nt LEFT JOIN nt2 ON id=t_id;
```

So, I need this complexity?  this new table arrange will consume less disk spacess. The use of

```
SELECT id, name FROM nt WHERE name>'john';      -- Q1A 
SELECT id, name FROM nt_full WHERE name>'john'; -- Q1B
SELECT id, name FROM t WHERE name>'john';       -- Q1C

SELECT id, xcontent FROM nt_full WHERE name>'john'; -- Q2A
SELECT id, xcontent FROM t WHERE name>'john';       -- Q2B
```

So, in theory, all the performances of Q1A vs Q1B vs Q1C will be the same?
And Q2A vs Q2B?

Comment: There is no widely accepted answer to this, as it's highly dependent on your particular data, and your access pattern, and what operations need to be fast (searches vs. updates, for example).  In general, I start off as normalized as I can get, do some testing with mock data, and adjust from there.

Comment: Once you start storing XML, you are beyond storage efficiency anyway. (and beyond 1NF too, probably)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question "how much space does a null value take" is: no space at all - at least not in the "data" area.

For each nullable column in the table there is one **bit** in the row header that marks the column value as null (or not null). So the "space" that the null values takes is already present in the row header - regardless whether the column is null or not.

Thus the null "value" does not occupy any space in the data block storing the row.

This is documented in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-page-layout.html

---

Postgres will not store long string values (xml, varchar, text, json, ...) in the actual data block if it exceeds a certain threshold (about 2000 bytes). If the value is longer than that, it will be stored in a special storage area "away" from your actual data. So splitting up the table into two tables with a 1:1 relationship doesn't really by you that much. Unless you are storing a **lot** of rows (hundreds of millions), I doubt you will be able to notice the difference - but this also depends on your usage patterns.

The data that is stored "out-of-line" is also automatically compressed.

Details about this can be found in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html

---

One reason why the separate table *might* be an advantage is the necessary "vacuum" cleanup. If you update the XML data a **lot** but the rest of the table hardly ever changes, then splitting this up in two tables might improve the overall performance because "XML table" will need less "maintenance" and the "main" table won't be changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

A varchar field consumes 2 bytes more than the content.
so if you define it as varchar(250)
and put 10 chars in, it consumes 12 bytes
100 chars consumes 102 bytes
NULL consumes 2 bytes. no problem.

if you are in some situation where you need to store large amounts of xml data
and end up using a (for instance) blob type, you should put that in another table
and keep your primary table lean and fast

Comment: "*NULL consumes 2 bytes*" - not true. a NULL value does not consume any space. It's just a bit in the header. The bitmask in the header is only as big as the nullable columns in the table require. So if there are 16 nullable columns in the table, **all** columns together require 2 additional bytes to store null values. The XML value will be stored outside of the table anyway if the value exceeds a certain limit, keeping the primary table lean and fast automatically.